# Find the object with specific product type and get id from URL and join by comma using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have set of array of objects containing url, product type where I want to filter the producttype and split the id from url and join by comma

if productType is "ESJ:001" I want to pass the id else
if prductType is "ESJ003" I want to pass the empty data
Also if there is "undefined" I want to pass it an empty.

```
let obj= [ 
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com', productType:'ESJ001'}
{ url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=005&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com', productType:'ESJ001'}
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com' productType:'ESJ003'}
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com'}
]
```

Expected output:

```
001,005,,
```

Here is my code
I am able to get 001,005 but not sure how to include empty data for ESJ003 and undefined

Output I am getting

```
001,005
```

expected output

```
001,005,,
```

```js
let obj= [ 
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com', productType:'ESJ001'},
{ url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=005&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com', productType:'ESJ001'},
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com', productType:'ESJ003'},
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApiid=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com'}
]
let urlIds = obj.filter(x=>x.productType === 'ESJ001').map(x => new URL(x?.url).searchParams.get('id'));
    urlIds = urlIds.map(value => value === "undefined" ? "" : value);
    let joinedUrlIds = urlIds.join(',');
    console.log(joinedUrlIds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting only two values because you're filtering out those that don't match `x.productType === 'ESJ001'`.
To get the expected output, you can do this:

```js
let obj = [{
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com',
    productType: 'ESJ001'
  },
  {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=005&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com',
    productType: 'ESJ001'
  },
  {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com',
    productType: 'ESJ003'
  },
  {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApiid=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com'
  }
]
const urlIds = obj.map(x => (x.productType === 'ESJ001' ? new URL(x?.url).searchParams.get('id') : ''))
  .map(value => value === 'undefined' ? '' : value);
const joinedUrlIds = urlIds.join();
console.log(joinedUrlIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do something like this, even simpler code:

```js
const getID = (url) => new URL(url).searchParams.get('id')
const data = obj.map(data => data.productType === 'ESJ001' ? getID(data.url) : 
"")

console.log(data)
```

I think your filter is problematic here